# KB4013198 Causes StackOverflowException in VirtualizingStackPanel

Tags: wpf, stack-overflow, virtualizingstackpanel

I have a customer who is on Windows 10 v1511 (i.e., not the Anniversary Update).  After installing update KB4013198, my WPF application now crashes periodically when scrolling a ListBox employing a VirtualizingStackPanel.  I was able to build a VM with the appropriate Windows version and reproduce the issue with the debugger attached - the actual error is a StackOverflowException generated in VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl.

There was no code change on my part - the prior to applying the Windows Update, everything works; after applying the update, the error occurs.

Upgrading to the Anniversary Update also solve the problem.

I'm at a bit of a loss to even start going about tweaking the XAML of my application to attempt to resolve this issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should run the application with the clr profiler to see what in the clr happens. You can download it here: https://clrprofiler.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is probably not very helpful, but we had a similar problem a while ago - on some clients' computers a VirtualizingStackPanel with lots of items would fall into an endless loop while updating its ScrollInfo, due to some rounding error. It turned out that this only happened if the client had a newer .Net-Framework installed, which did an in-place update on VirtualizingStackPanel, introducing this bug. We eventually replaced the entire control because we failed to find a work-around that didn't cause other problems.